# GridView RowUpdating cannot change column value

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I'm trying to change a column value on a gridview (.net 3.5) using the RowUpdating event.
The event is fired and I set a new value  - but the table is not updated.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewHotels" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceHotels" 
        OnRowUpdating="GridViewHotels_RowUpdating">
```

...

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="lat" HeaderText="lat" SortExpression="lat" />
```

...

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceHotels" runat="server" 
               UpdateCommand="UPDATE [hotels] SET ... [lat] = @lat .... WHERE [id] = @id">
```

This is the event code (which is called):

```
    protected void GridViewHotels_RowUpdating(Object sender, 
GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        e.NewValues["lat"] = "xxx";
    }
```

And yet ,the "lat" field is not updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your grid datasource bound to? If it is a dataset you're keeping in ViewState, etc, you will have to call [AcceptChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges.aspx) and rebind the data. If the underlying data is in a database, simply rebind the grid from the data source (after updating it), i.e. refresh it from sql server/whatever your data source is.

Comment: It is bound to a database.
Calling GridViewHotels.DataBind(); after setting the value, is that it ?

Comment: If its bound to the database, you should have a method that fetches the data to be bound correct? You will need to basically execute the same call that initially populates the grid. Also when you save the new value, you have to persist those changes to the database as well. Simply setting the field value will not work.

Comment: The update is done automatically on the UpdateCommand command which is set on the SqlDataSource , isn't it ?
Should I set this Update command on my code ?
(Something like SqlDataSourceHotels.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE...")

Comment: correct - if you're update command is handling this and you have set it, make sure the update is executed and you rebind your data using the select command of the sql data source

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a connection string in your SQLDataSource.

Comment: Ranch, select the SQLDataSource in Design mode and choose 'Configure Data Source' and see if you have it connected to anything.  If not, that's the first thing you need to address.

Comment: Sorry for posting a partial code, but I do have a connection string. The page is working perfectly, except for the fact the I cannot modify the values in the code.